# Website functionality (data to html generating)

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I already have the info i need in the database. I know how to display the data on the main page, but i only show a small part of info there.

What i need is when i click on the *read more* i want it to *link to a full info* page.
How to i accomplish that? Do i have to make/generate a html file for every car i have and link the info from the main page to it? Or what is the correct technique for achieving this ?

Comment: Dude i know how to display the data i have.

Comment: I think you are looking for a combination of templating and url routing.  I would suggest looking into a PHP framework like Laravel.

Comment: Good idea, i could make a html template for the info about the car and insert the information i have about that specific car.

Comment: Ok, so you just have to create a list of your cars with a "view" link. The target of this link is a php script (detail.php?id=12 for exmample where the id parameter is the id of the car). Now, in the detail script, you juste have to get your param with $_GET['id'] and then, ask your database to retrieve this id's car data. That's it

Comment: Well that clears things up :)) why did i get so many - ? I think it's a relevant question for newbies like me who don't know all the techniques used in web development. I learned something form this thank you.

Comment: You don't have to use a PHP framework like CodeIgniter.  However, if you read their documentation and follow the included tutorials, what you need will become more clear.  Then you can do it yourself from scratch, with CodeIgniter or with another framework.

Comment: Most likely because it is a wall of text and there really isn't a clearly defined question. A much better question would have been "here is what I am trying to do, here is what i've tried", etc.

Comment: Ah ok, i'll do my best to be more define next time. Thnx for clearing that up :)

Comment: No problem. You will find this site is amazing when you have developed that ability. We need enough info to work with, but not a whole lot of unnecessary information either.Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to have a list of cars on a main page, and then clicking on one of these cars would bring you to a details page with more information about that specific car.

This is a common situation. You'd simply have your main page query your car table and format that as a list of cars, each with a link to a details page like /details/12345 where the number represents the ID of the car you want to see. Then your details page would get the ID from the URL, query your database for details of that car ID, and assemble the page with those details.

Comment: Thanks for summing it up. Hope this threat will be helpful to other newbies like me xe xe :)